# Jenkins slave set-up - both master and slave nodes are Linux machines

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh

I want to set up a Linux node as a slave to the Jenkins master. I was going through [the tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) on setting it up for a Linux machine.

> Have master launch slave agent via SSH
>
> Jenkins has a built-in SSH client implementation that it can use to
>   talk to remote sshd and start a slave agent. This is the most
>   convenient and preferred method for Unix slaves, which normally has
>   sshd out-of-the-box. Click Manage Jenkins, then Manage Nodes, then
>   click "New Node." In this set up, you'll supply the connection
>   information (the slave host name, user name, and ssh credential). Note
>   that the slave will need the master's public ssh key copied to
>   ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

When it says `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` does it mean that I need to have the public key in this location on the node when logged in as a `jenkins` user (which is the username that the Master uses to log into the slaves)?

What does `~` signify? Which user's home directory are we talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be precise,

- the public key to be copied is **the public key of the user running the master**
- the destination is the **`.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the user on the slave** (ie, the user whose credentials you select for the ssh connection on the Jenkins node config page).

The `~` character is expanded by most shells to the current user's home directory (e.g., `/home/userxyz`).

Answer (score 1):

`~` means the user that is running Jenkins.

And yes, `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` means `authorized_keys` for the Jenkins user (the one running on your Jenkins server, not literally `jenkins`).

Comment: Thanks! I am still confused. I have a user named `jenkins` with a private key configured in the `Manage Credentials` area. So it is the corresponding public key that needs to go into `/home/jenkins/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the slave node. Am i correct? Also, is there some flexibility to this location - can i have it at `/data/jenkins/.ssh/authorized_keys` (some place common to more than one user trying to access the node)?

Comment: You can also paste your slave machines private key directly by using "Enter directly" option under "SSH Username with password"

Comment: I think this answer could benefit from a clearer explanation.